# Inherit SerialPort and manually trigger DataReceived event

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have an application which connects to serial port and assigns DataReceived event.

```
sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived);

void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{                
    string input = sp.ReadExisting();
}
```

I would like to create TestSerialPort  class that inherits SerialPort and allows me to trigger DataReceived event manually. Class should also override   ReadExisting() so I can return test value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  There's no OnDataReceived() method like there normally is to raise an event because calling it would always be wrong.  And ReadExisting is not virtual so you can't override it.

There's thus no point in inheriting, you have to replace it.  Or fake actual data transmission with a null modem emulator like com0com.  Find more options by googling "mock serialport".